# Connectionless UDP vs connection-oriented TCP over an open connection

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

If a TCP connection is established between a client and server, is sending data faster on this connection-oriented route compared to a connectionless given there is less header info in the packets? So a TCP connection is opened and bytes sent down the open connection as and when required.  Or would UDP still be a better choice via a connectionless route where each packet contains the destination address?

Is sending packets via an established TCP connection (after all hand shaking has been done) a method to be faster than UDP?

Comment: They are too different to be usefully compared that way. A 747 is faster than walking, but a 747 won't get you down a staircase.

Comment: Unwarranted assumption: "given there is less header info in the [TCP] packets [than in the UDP packets]".  What makes you think that? A UDP header is 8 bytes. A TCP header is at least 20 bytes.

Comment: 2nd unwarrented assumption: only on a "connectionless route" does "each packet contain the destination address." Every packet contains the destination address, regardless of whether the packet carries TCP or UDP.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far guys.  I understand in principle why I'd use TCP over UDP - not the question, reliability isn't a consideration.  I was asking from the angle of look ups in switching tables based on the header info (TCP) after a connection is open as opposed to a header containing all destination info (UDP).  If I wanted to get a single byte from source to destination could an open TCP connection be a better approach? The packet ordering is good point - thanks Joel.

Comment: Ah Ok. have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4 look up in switching tables does not relate to TCP or UDP. It is based on IP and this information is in IP header. So doesn't matter which one you are using. But again for TCP you might have more packets meaning you need to do more look ups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read a little bit more about this topic.

just as a quick answer. **TCP makes sure that all the packages are delivered**. So if one is dropped for whatever reason. The sender will continue sending it until the receiver gets it. However, **UDP sends a packet and just forgets it**, so you might loose some of the packets. As a result of this, UDP sends less number of packets over network.

This is why they use UDP for videos because first loosing small amount of data is not a big deal plus even if the sender sends it again it is too late for receiver to use it, so UDP is better. In contrast, you don't want your online banking be over UDP!

Edit: Remember, the speed of sending packets for both UDP and TCP is almost same, and depends on the network! However, after handshake is done in TCP, still receiver needs to send the acks, and sender has to wait for ack before sending new batch of data, so still would be a little slower.

Answer (score 0):

In general, TCP is marginally slower, despite less header info, because the packets must arrive in order, and, in fact, must arrive.  In a UDP situation, there is no checking of either.

Comment: Which means you have to do the checking, and since there's no flow control in UDP, you might lose packets rather easy. And you probably cannot do the checking yourself faster than TCP.

Comment: I doubt that TCP has less header info than UDP. Can you cite a source? (Here are mine: [udp header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure), [tcp header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)).

Comment: TCP headers are bigger than UDP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: See [connectionless and connection-oriented packet switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching).  Once a TCP connection is opened does the destination "lookup" on each network node effectively have less overheads?

Comment: @frimley - the otherwise reasonable article is flawed by its suggestion that TCP is a circuit-switched protocol. It isn't. It is a realiable transport protocol that is carried by IP. IP is almost always* a packet-switched protocol. So, TCP or UDP are always packet-switched, never circuit-switched. (*"almost always" == "except for MPLS").

Comment: If you're in a situation where a missed packet is not an issue, then you don't actually need to do the checking.  An example of that would be streaming seismic data, or VOIP